# python - py-expression-eval - Passing a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, eval

I am using [py-expression-eval](https://github.com/Axiacore/py-expression-eval) library for evaluating an expression.

```
import numpy as np
from py_expression_eval import Parser
parser=Parser()
a = np.array([1,2,3])
parser.parse('x*5').evaluate({'x':a})
#Works and outputs
array([  5.,  10.,  15.])
```

However:

```
parser.parse('sin(x)').evaluate({'x':a})
```

throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#52>", line 1, in <module>
parser.parse('sin(x)').evaluate({'x':a})
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py_expression_eval\__init__.py", line 133, in evaluate
nstack.append(f(n1))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

But if I pass values of array one by one it works:

```
parser.parse('sin(x)').evaluate({'x':a[0]})
0.8414709848078965
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `sin` is hardwired to `math.sin`. Replacing it with `np.sin` works:

```
parser.ops1['sin'] = np.sin
parser.parse('sin(x)').evaluate({'x':a})

array([ 0.84147098,  0.90929743,  0.14112001])
```

Operators are in `ops2`:

```
parser.ops2['^'] = np.power
parser.parse('x^2').evaluate({'x':a})

array([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Thanks..Works with cos, tan, asin, acos, atan, log ,ceil ,floor, round, exp functions also. Now only problem is '^', which is implemented using math.pow function. Replacing with np.power doesnot work.

Comment: Added a solution for `^`.

Comment: whoa....Thanks....I was certain that I used ops2...It didn't work yesterday....But now it is working...:)